# Setting TextInput placeholder vertically center in ios - React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, styles

I'm using a `TextInput` in my `react-native` application and found a strange issue. The placeholder used in my TextInput is not vertically centered in ios devices but it's centered in android devices. How can i fix this issue?

Code

```
 <View style={{marginBottom: 20}}>
      <Text style={styles.subTitle}>Description</Text>
      <TextInput style={[styles.inputFull_80]} multiline={true} placeholder="Enter group description" underlineColorAndroid='transparent'/>
 </View>
```

Style

```
const styles = {
    container: {
        //TODO: Remove once added properly
        marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'white',

    },

    subTitle: {

        fontFamily: 'gotham',
        marginBottom: 5,
        fontSize: 16,
        color: '#4A4A50',


    },

    inputFull_80: {

        minHeight: 80,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#E6E6E6',
        fontFamily: 'gotham_light',
        borderRadius: 4,
        fontSize: 14,
        padding: 10,


    },


};
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `textAlign={'center'}` as a property to the TextInput component

Comment: textAlign is an horizontal alignement, not a vertical one